# Deezer `X-Frame-Options`` | Cuando uso DZ.getLoginStatus(), y si recargo la pagina "OAuthException" se pierden los datos

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, sdk

**(REACT APP)**.
Primeramente esta es la configuracion de mi app en deezer:

- Activate: [True]
- Application name: 'Nombre de mi app'
- Application domain: localhost:5173
- Redirect URL after authentication: http://localhost:5173/home
- Category: Tools

En mi view de `/auth` tengo dos botonos y que manejan esta funcion:

```
  const enterWith = (social) => {
    if (social === 'guest') {

    }
    if (social === 'deezer') {
      var userToken;
      DZ.login((response) => {
        console.log(response)
        if (response.authResponse) {
          console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
          console.log('OK! This is your id: ', response.userID)
          DZ.api(`/user/me`, (response) => {
            console.log('User: ', response)
            console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
            navigate('/home')
          });
          userToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
          console.log(userToken)
        } else {
          console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
        }
      }, { perms: 'basic_access, email, offline_access, manage_library, manage_community, delete_library, listening_history' });
    }
  }
```

Y en mi view de `/home` tengo tres botones para pedir las playlists del usuario que se autenticó, la cual si me muestran sus playlists, pero si recargo la pagina me da el error de:

```
  const testReqPlaylists = () => {
    DZ.api(`/user/me/playlists`, (response) => {
      console.log('Playlists of this user: ', response);
    });
  }

  const checkLoginStatus = () => {
    console.log('Asking for the status: ');
    DZ.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
      if (response.authResponse) {
        console.log('Exists: ', response)
      } else {
        console.log('Does not exists: ', response)
      }
    });
  }

  const logOut = () => {
    console.log('Logging out...')
    DZ.logout((response) => { console.log(response) });
  }
```

Ademas tengo el boton para verificar el estado de conexion del usuario, que es el `checkLoginStatus()`

Y me da esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Inicialmente funcionaba correctamente cuando usaba la funcion para verificar el estado de conexion `checkLoginStatus()`, y si recargaba la pagina y pedia las playlists tambien funcionaba.
Pensaba que el token una vez que expiraba haria refresh, pero una vez que expiró. Al usar esa funcion `checkLoginStatus()` me muestra `The loading of “https://connect.deezer.com/oauth/auth.php?app_id=0000000&format=channel&redirect_uri=http://localhost:5173/home&response_type=token” in a frame is denied by “X-Frame-Options“ directive set to “SAMEORIGIN“.`
Yo pense que era porque necesitaba loguearme de nuevo, pero si me logueo y verifico la conexion, me sale lo mismo, ademas que si recargo la pagina se pierden los datos del usuario.

Por favor ayuda :')